# How to get method name win 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

How to get the current method name in win 8(WinRT) app ... earlier in wp7 we could use `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` but its not there anymore thanks

Comment: Do you mean in WinRT? `GetCurrentMethod` is certainly in .NET 4.5..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, .NETCore lacks a lot of such things... and don't even get me *started* on `GetTypeInfo()` ! But perhaps a pragmatic workaround is to get the **compiler** to do it for you?

```
string CallerName([CallerMemberName]string caller = "")
{
    return caller;
}
...
string name = CallerName();
```

Comment: @CognitiveDesire it'll be faster, too - zero reflection. So if you are using multiple target frameworks, it would be worth considering using this on all those that support it.

Answer (score 1):

This option can be helpfull if you need to override a method

```
private string GetMethodName(Expression<Action> expression)
{
    var methodName = (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name;
    return methodName;
}
```

Then just call it like

```
GetMethodName(() => TheNameOfTheCallingMethod());
```